# Add strings to zsh tab completion for all commands and arguments

Tags: command-line, zsh, tab-completion

I want to add the keywords `foo` and `bar` to be added to the auto completion results for any command or argument.

eg:

`cd <TAB>` should give foo and bar in the suggestions in addition to the existing completions

`blah <TAB>` should give foo and bar  in the suggestions in addition to the existing completions.

The zsh completion articles i have been reading mention methods to add completions to specific commands, but none mention how to add a set of words to global completions ( or if there is a global completion list which always exist )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had to dig through the [zshcompsys manual](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html) to find out the right commands

The below code at the end of `~/.zshrc` works for me

```bash
function _my_completions() {
  local -a mywords
  mywords=( foo bar )
  compadd -a mywords
}
compdef _my_completions -first-
```

The important flag here is the context `-first-`. As per the zshcompsys man page:

```
-first-
     This is tried before any other completion function.  The function called
     may set the _compskip parameter to one of various values: all: no further
     completion is attempted; a string containing the substring patterns: no
     pattern completion functions will be called; a string containing default:
     the function for the `-default-' context will not be called, but
     functions defined for commands will
```

Comment: Thanks, we used this to integrate zsh-autosuggesion with the completion system: https://gist.github.com/olejorgenb/678ddc534c157ffb7c61151cf8eb8d03